# How to obtain Assembly Info from AssemblyID in COR Profiler?

Tags: c++, .net, clr-profiling-api

I want to capture all the loaded assemblies' info along with the metadata like Public Key, Version, etc. To do so, I have developed the .Net custom profiler using ICorProfiling APIs and Callbacks. I can capture the Loaded Assembly ID by subscribing to the AssemblyLoadFinished event. But from this AssemblyID, how do I get the assembly metadata like Public Key, Version, etc.

I found a method 'IMetaDataAssemblyImport::GetAssemblyProps'. But it accepts the assembly token (i.e. mdAssembly). How do I convert AssemblyID to mdAssembly?

Answer (score 2):

Metadata tokens (including the assembly metadata token) are module specific and a manifested module can only define one assembly, so there is really only one assembly metadata token anyway; but you should probably use [IMetaDataAssemblyImport::GetAssemblyFromScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/metadata/imetadataassemblyimport-getassemblyfromscope-method) rather than hard coding it.

The real question is how to get the correct IMetaDataAssemblyImport instance for the AssemblyID. You could use [ICorProfilerInfo::GetAssemblyInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilerinfo-getassemblyinfo-method) to get the module id of the manifest module and then [ICorProfilerInfo::GetModuleMetaData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilerinfo-getmodulemetadata-method) to get the IMetaDataAssemblyImport instance.

Comment: Thanks Brian for the respond. What type should I specify for publicKey argument in the GetAssemblyProps method?

Comment: Depends, if you don't want the public key then just pass in null. If you do want the public key, then pass in a reference to where it can write the pointer to the assembly key.

Comment: Yes, I need it and that's what I want to understand how do I pass the reference? I mean, first, how do I declare (what type) the variable?

Comment: It's all very straight forward `void *keyPtr; ULONG keyLen; hr = aImport.GetAssemblyProps(mdAssembly, &keyPtr, &keyLen, ...` then keyPtr will contain a pointer to the key and keyLen will be the length of the key.

Comment: Here, I am marking keyPtr as const i.e. const void *keyPtr; and it is throwing  error stating 'Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF'. You can see my code here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5e2b331b-5240-4e20-9723-e9322584f65d/how-to-obtain-assembly-info-from-assemblyid-in-cor-profiler?forum=clr&prof=required

Comment: If I don't mark const then build is failing with error 'cannot convert argument 2 from 'void **' to 'const void **''

Comment: What was the HRESULT? did you initialize the variables before calling GetAssemblyProps? `const void *keyPtr` sounds more correct, my guess is that GetAssemblyProps didn't set it for one reason or another and you ended up dereferencing garbage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165899/discussion-between-hitesh-and-brian-reichle).